Generate SVG image of highchart Scatter chart using highchart Configuration
I am trying to generate a svg image of  high chart using a high chart configuration.
Configuration contains  symbol a as customize svg  64 bit string but this configuration gives me error "Namespace prefix xlink for href on image is not defined".
below mentioned is the configuration i am using .
 "marker": {
             "symbol": "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIzMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMiI+PHJlY3QgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMiIgd2lkdGg9IjMyIiB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiBmaWxsPSJyZ2JhKDE1NCwxMywxMjgsMSkiLz48dGV4dCBmb250LXNpemU9IjExIiBmb250LXdlaWdodD0iNzAwIiBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iTmV1ZSBIYWFzIEdyb3Rlc2s7QXJpYWwsc2Fucy1zZXJpZiIgeD0iMzUlIiB5PSI2MCUiIGZpbGw9IndoaXRlIj5BPC90ZXh0Pjwvc3ZnPg==)"

            }

I have tried to set href and other property, but didn't worked.

There's no href in your sample, nor is there an image element. The problem must be elsewhere in code you haven't shown us.

decode that Base64 string in an online decoder. Modern browsers do accept raw SVG, base64 not required; only have to escape the # with %23
